# MongoError: database names cannot contain the character '/'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am using moongoose npm package. When I try to connect with mongodb I am getting this error.  Here is my code.

```html
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1/27017/task-manager-api", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", {
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
  },
});

const me = new User({
  name: "Sushant",
  age: 17,
});

me.save()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(me);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error Spotted");
  });
```

MongoError: database names cannot contain the character '/'

Answer (score 1):

Port number should be added with colon instead of forward slash

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    });
    
    const User = mongoose.model("User", {
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      age: {
        type: Number,
      },
    });
    
    const me = new User({
      name: "Sushant",
      age: 17,
    });
    
    me.save()
      .then(() => {
        console.log(me);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error Spotted");
      });
```

Comment: @Rekepaw Please accept the answer if it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your db URI contains a small typo mistake, as you wrote:
`mongodb://127.0.0.1/27017/task-manager-api`

While it should be:
`mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/task-manager-api`